# CSS Sprites, puzzle

Tags: html, css

May be this seems silly question for you guys.. Its about CSS Sprites. I have a navigation which contains 4 menus like.. HOME COMPANY SERVICES SUPPORT although I used a css sprite that have 3 mode/state for static, hover and selected(class called 'current'). I used to call them like..

```
ul#top-nav-links {list-style:none; background:url(../images/nav-bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0; width:508px; height:35px; float:left; margin-left:80px; margin-top:33px; padding-left:4px; margin-right:23px;}
ul#top-nav-links li{float:left; position:relative; z-index:99999;}
ul#top-nav-links li a.home01{background:url(../images/nav.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0; display:block; width:100px; height:31px; text-indent:-999px; float:left;}
ul#top-nav-links li a.company01{background:url(../images/nav.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0; display:block; width:150px; height:31px; text-indent:-999px; float:left; background-position:-100px 0px;}
ul#top-nav-links li a.services01{background:url(../images/nav.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0; display:block; width:140px; height:31px; text-indent:-999px; float:left; background-position:-250px 0px;}
ul#top-nav-links li a.support01{background:url(../images/nav.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0; display:block; width:115px; height:31px; text-indent:-999px; float:left; background-position:-390px 0px;}

ul#top-nav-links li a.current{background:url(../images/nav.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -62px; display:block; width:100px; height:31px; text-indent:-999px; float:left;}
```

and here is the image I used [image]

so I need to display the middle colored one on hover state, although the last one for the current state, of course the current state wasn't need hover effect..

I know, It should call like this..

```
ul#top-nav-links li a.company01:hover{background-position:-100px -31px;}
```

but I curious if somehow that code should be shortened by avoiding to call each menu as separate instead like this...

```
ul#top-nav-links li a:hover(background-position:0px -31px;}
```

the above one I tried but the horizontal positioning of the image wasn't possible..

Any thoughts?

drop down a comment, if this question was confused.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive about cross-browser support, but this at least works in Chrome 15.

http://jsfiddle.net/tkZMB/

```
li:hover {
    background-position-y: -31px;
}
```

You could combine this to simplify your overall CSS too.

```
/* General list item declaration */
li { 
    width: 130px; 
    height: 30px; 
    border: 1px solid gray; 
    float: left;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5HOI.png);
}

/* For each child move menu over */    
li:nth-child(2) {
    background-position-x: -100px;
}

/* On hover slide the background up. */
li:hover {
    background-position-y: -62px;
}
```

Comment: the nth-child is probably not the best idea if you have the probability of adding new items into your navigation. I'd go with class based selectors(IMHO). otherwise +1

Comment: @mrtsherman this is appreciating, but I can't easily get rid of the cross browser support especially not working in FF.

Comment: I think you are out of luck then =(

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just modified your code to this, though I hope this will help you to produce efficient markup *(semantically-correct)* and style sheet codes: *hopeful that will also solve browser inconsistencies in your codes*.

### HTML:

```
<ul class="section">
    <li class="home current">
        <a href="#" title="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="company">
        <a href="#" title="">Company</a>
    </li>
    <li class="services">
        <a href="#" title="">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="support">
        <a href="#" title="">Support</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS:

```
.section li {
    display: inline;
}
.section a {
    background: url(../images/nav.png) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}
.section .home a {
    background-position: left top;
}
.section .company a {
    background-position: -100px 0;
}
.section .services a {
    background-position: -250px 0;
}
.section .support a {
    background-position: -390px 0;
}
.section .current a {
    background-position: 0 -62px;
}
```